# U-SQL (Azure Data Lake language) script error

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

Using sample script from a [Data Lake Analytics tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-lake-analytics-analyze-weblogs/), the following error occurs when building the script:

```
E_CSC_USER_SYNTAXERROR: syntax error. Expected one of: RETURN '[' ALTER COMBINE CREATE DECLARE DEPLOY DROP END EXTRACT IF INSERT OUTPUT PROCESS REDUCE REFERENCE RESOURCE SELECT SET TABLE TRUNCATE UPDATE USE USING VIEW identifier quoted-identifier variable ';' '('
```

The error line is the last line of the script. The script in the tutorial does end with an OUTPUT statement, which the syntax error is saying is expected.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like we may have an error in the example. We are investigating. Will update as soon as we learn more.

Comment: The sample script has been fixed.

Answer (score 4):

(Azure DL Team here as well): We identified the issues and are going to fix it. In the mean time:

1. Please split the script that does the create and load and then query into two scripts: one that does the create and load, and one that does the query.
2. The end of the definition of the TVF (before DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ) needs an END;

I hope this helps.
Michael